# Server throws an exception only when debugging

Tags: c#, debugging, null

I have an api call to search an object from my data base with 3 fields. (string, datetimestart, datetimeend).
When I execute this it works perfectly:

```
entryAPI.entriesSearch = function (item) {
    return $http.post("./api/search/", { Matter: item.Matter, StartDate: item.StartDate, EndDate: item.EndDate});
};
```

The problem is that when I attach debugger and put a breakpoint in the call, the item receiving seems to be null and obviously it throws an exception.

```
public HttpResponseMessage Post(Entities.TimeSheet.SearchFields item)
{
    try
    {
        // do some stuff (that is correctly done when not debugging
        // item value is null when debugging
    }
```

This is my SearchFields item:

```
public class SearchFields
{
    public string Matter { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
}
```

The search works perfectly fine but I want to track some values now and I am not able to do so, I have no idea how to solve/search how to solve something like this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What if you replace `{ Matter: item.Matter, ...` with `item = { Matter: item.Matter, ...`?

Comment: Use Fiddler to check what is *really* sent to the application and how things are different from one call to the other. MVC's data binding doesn't change behaviour during debugging. The effective URL may be different since you use `./api/search`. Or the data may be different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think [FromBody]  is missing.

Like:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody] Entities.TimeSheet.SearchFields item)
{
    try
    {
        // do some stuff (that is correctly done when not debugging
        // item value is null when debugging
    }
```

Comment: This totally worked out. It is weird because I had another call to post the item itself and worked without the "frombody". I thought it was only necessary with primary types. Thank you very much really.

Comment: I did once the same:-) You're welcom